# Binding multiple datatable inside Repeating section grouping by one of the column of one of the data set

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I have repeating section in Oracle BI Publisher report. In this repeater I wants to bind two data tables from two different data models (Data Sets). Both the data sets are linked with a common column. Now the issue is with the link  dt1.col1 --> dt2.col1, the dt1 data set repeats the whole dt2 records. Thus duplicate records being displayed. How can I avoid this scenario ?

Comment: Can you update with the programming you already have? Like the for-eaches and if statements? If you can provide a sample of the data XML, that would also help.

Comment: I have used online editor. As a newbie I don't know how to provide you the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a variable to keep the link. Here's a basic example.

If you have data set:

```
<data>
<set1>
<row>
<attribute1>A</attribute1>
<attribute2>A1</attribute2>
<attribute3>A11</attribute3>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>B</attribute1>
<attribute2>B1</attribute2>
<attribute3>B11</attribute3>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>C</attribute1>
<attribute2>C1</attribute2>
<attribute3>C11</attribute3>
</row>
</set1>
<set2>
<row>
<attribute1>A</attribute1>
<attribute4>A2</attribute4>
<attribute5>A22</attribute5>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>B</attribute1>
<attribute4>B2.1</attribute4>
<attribute5>B22.1</attribute5>
</row>
<row>
<attribute1>B</attribute1>
<attribute4>B2.2</attribute4>
<attribute5>B22.2</attribute5>
</row>
</set2>
</data>
```

You would have your report code look something like:

```
<?for-each:data/set1/row?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v_record', attribute1)?>
Record: <?attribute1?>
Attribute2: <?attribute2?>
Attribute3: <?attribute3?>
Linked Records:
<?for-each:../../set2/row?>
<?if:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'v_record')=attribute1?>
--Attribute4: <?attribute4?>
--Attribute5: <?attribute5?>
<?end if?>
<?end for-each?>
End

<?end for-each?>
```

Processed report would show:

```
Record: A
Attribute2: A1
Attribute3: A11
Linked Records:
--Attribute4: A2
--Attribute5: A22
End

Record: B
Attribute2: B1
Attribute3: B11
Linked Records:
--Attribute4: B2.1
--Attribute5: B22.1
--Attribute4: B2.2
--Attribute5: B22.2
End

Record: C
Attribute2: C1
Attribute3: C11
Linked Records:
End
```